# Spring boot + Jersey parse Response JSON data

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, jersey-client

I am trying to build a simple page the will display some places on the map. I'm really new to rest in Java and i'm using Spring boot + jersey framework.

I'm using [google places api](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/?hl=pt-br) to search for places, i made the GET respond for a lat/lng that i'm passing thru PostMan:

```
http://localhost:9000/res/-23.558712/-46.592235
```

Inside the code im calling:

```
@GET
@Path("/{lat}/{lng}")
@Produces("application/json")
public void getBook(@PathParam("lat") String lat,@PathParam("lng") String lng) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    getdata();
}
public static void getdata(){
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    String entity = client.target("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+ lat + "," + lng + "&radius=5000&types=market&name=dia&key=MY_KEY")
            .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            .header("some-header", "true")
            .get(String.class);
    System.out.println(entity);
}
```

And i get a really big Json in the response:

```
"results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -23.5703071,
           "lng" : -46.58153289999999
        },
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : -23.56895811970849,
              "lng" : -46.5801839197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -23.5716560802915,
              "lng" : -46.58288188029149
           }
        }
     },....
```

And much more, my question is, how do i parse this JSON response to away that i can manage data? I want to get, name, location... to plot on the map.
I will have to create a model class with all response parameters?

I really don't know if this is all wrong.

Comment: This resource falls under reverse geocoding and if you need name of the location you should get it from "fromatted_address" attiribute, and address components will give you exact address. The following link has some information which might help you further.   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding

Answer (score 0):

This resource falls under reverse geocoding and if you need name of the location you should get it from "fromatted_address" attiribute, and address components will give you exact address. The following link has some information which might help you further.   [reverse geocoding] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: Maybe i was not clear enough in my question, my problem was in parsing the response.

Comment: in your case entity is your response.  then . parsing goes like this...use Jackson to parse the entity.                                                                 JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(entity);                     
        if(node != null){
   JsonNode results = node.get("results");  
   if(results.anArray()){ 
    for(int i=0;i<results.length;i++){ 
     String address = results.get(i).get("formattedAddress")
       }
    }
   }
 }